# ¿Se puede cambiar el formato del <input type="date"> en HTML?

Tags: html, date, input, date-format

Estoy tratando de pedir al usuario que rellena el formulario que inserte una fecha, en este caso sería la de la caducidad de la tarjeta de crédito por lo que el formato requerido es mm/yyyy y no dd/mm/yyyy. Es posible que el usuario no tenga que meter el día?

```
Caducidad (Més/año) <br> <input type="date"><br>
```

Comment: No olvides revisar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante Jquery UI.

```javascript
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
     });
  });
 </script>

<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
 display: none;
 }
</style>
```

Y en el formulario:

```html
 <form  method="post" name="formreport" id="formreport"  >
      <p><input name="fecha" type="text" id="fecha" value="" class="date-picker"></p>
      <p>
 </form>
```

[*fuente*](https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/3317/jquery-ui-datepicker-para-mostrar-solo-el-mes-y-el-ano)